# Where is the _start function

Tags: c, macos, assembly, stack, programming-languages

Here is a minimal example:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {}
```

and then

```
% gcc main.c && otool -xv a.out
a.out:
(__TEXT,__text) section
_main:
0000000100003f9e    pushq   %rbp
0000000100003f9f    movq    %rsp, %rbp
0000000100003fa2    movl    %edi, -0x4(%rbp)
0000000100003fa5    movq    %rsi, -0x10(%rbp)
0000000100003fa9    movl    $0x0, %eax
0000000100003fae    popq    %rbp
0000000100003faf    retq
```

I am wondering why there is no `_start` function. I was attempting to dissassemble because I'd like to learn more about how the OS initializes the stack and how a program entry point actually works.

I tried looking at the [System V ABI](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/intel386-psABI-1.1.pdf), but even the section on the stack was not very enlightening.

MacOS.

Comment: `main` is usually called from code in `crt0`.

Comment: Is there a way to observe it @TomKarzes ? I've often heard `C` doesn't have a run-time, but it seems like it does have a very minimal one.

Comment: Unlike Linux, MacOS doesn't statically link a `_start` into every executable; they keep it in libc.  If you use GDB's `starti` command, or LLDB's equivalent if it has one, execution should stop at the first user-space instruction, wherever that is.  (On Linux that would be inside `ld.so`'s `_start`, not your own executable's, but IDK where it would be for macOS)

Comment: The `_start` function typically opens the standard file streams, it *might* initialize BSS and other static data, call "constructors" for global initialization, and then calls the `main` function. It does *not* create or allocate the stack. If you want to know that you should go even lower, into the kernel and its loader. If you really want to learn OS-/kernel-level design and code, I recommend [the OS-dev wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page), and investing in [some books](https://wiki.osdev.org/Books).

Comment: Thanks @Someprogrammerdude . This all stems from an unanswered question from my OS class on how the OS constructs the stack (on-demand or on initial program loading?) and how it communicates its relevant information to the program. I read OSTEP and have just finished a 10-week course, but neither answered these low-level, technical design questions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I suspect/hope the OP is hoping to *observe* the stack contents from `_start`, to see the SysV ABI's process-startup state in action.  (With argc and the elements of argv[] on the stack, pointed to by RSP.  The OS does of course allocate space for the stack as part of `execve` replacing the process with a fresh state, and also stores arg strings, env strings, and argv[] and envp[] on it before starting user-space, @user129...)

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes, you understood my intention. I want to know how `_start` works. Making a wild (but probably correct) guess, MacOS keeps their proprietary. As for the second thing you mention, I of course figured that, but my OS professor specifically said that only the initial code page is loaded into memory and all else loaded "on-demand". This didn't make sense to me since I thought the OS would have to do some work to initialize the stack, which it should do initially by 0'ing (or not) an anonymous page and filling its contents, rather than later upon a hardware trap.

Comment: The macOS kernel (Darwin) is open-source; so is its libc and most of the low-level Unixy parts.  Some of those parts derived from FreeBSD, others like the XNU kernel (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNU) have roots in Mach and even NeXTSTEP.

Comment: Actually, the macOS kernel [Dawrin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_(operating_system)) is open-source, together with a lot of the base OS-level systems.

Comment: I assume by "loaded" you mean "mapped", like `mmap` does.  For the pages backed by the executable file and libraries, an OS can implement `execve` as simply as just creating the data structures describing the mapping and returning to user-space.  The first code-fetch will then page fault, triggering the page containing `_start` to be "demand paged" if it wasn't already loaded in RAM (in the pagecache), then "wire" that page into the hardware page tables.  (continued...)

Comment: (...continued)   (Fun fact: Early Linux's very first implementation did that; later it does wire up more pages, at least the one containing the entry point, to avoid that initial fault.)  But the stack memory containing the args and environment isn't backed by any file, just swap space.  i.e. those are anonymous pages.    The kernel has to put that data somewhere, and it would make no sense to defer updating the page-table entry until the process tried to access it and faulted.  So at least those page(s) at the highest addresses of the stack region start out mapped and dirty.

Comment: Got it. Thanks @PeterCordes .You exactly answered my question. I was asking about the optimization you mentioned in the second part. While a minor thing, it is interesting to me (and something my Architecture professor last quarter couldn't answer). Interesting that you use the term "wire", you seem to use it in the same way as when I said "loaded" (actually put into physical memory). Also, I understand that those pages would start out "mapped" and "wired" (in the page table, and also in physical memory), but I do not see how they would be dirty (since the process hasn't written to it yet).

Comment: I use "wired" to describe having page-table entries pointing to physical pages, to distinguish from *logically* mapped, the mappings set up with `mmap` (and `execve`).  The kernel can handle those lazily, not actually allocating zeroed physical pages or loading from disk, and not creating page-table entries, until a page fault.  And can unwire them under memory pressure, in which case you'll get a page fault, but not an *invalid* page fault, instead soft or hard.  But that's transparent to the process, unlike if it did `munmap`.

Comment: As for "dirty", the process hasn't written them itself, but the kernel has on its behalf.    You have a stack page only backed by swap space (anonymous) with non-zero data in it (the only copy of that arg/env data), so the kernel can't evict the page without write-back to swap space.  In Linux, if you looked at `/proc/<PID>/smap`, those page(s) would be counted as part of "Private_Dirty" or Anonymous, IDK.  Unless paged out.  (Or if the OS allocates swap space and writes the data to disk without evicting it yet, then it would be a clean anonymous page, able to be dropped without further I/O.)

Comment: If you asked a different question, I could post these comments as an answer, if it's not already a duplicate.  It certainly doesn't answer the question we're commenting under, about where macOS keeps its `_start`.  (Which seems like a fine question if there isn't already a duplicate for it.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: In Apple’s use, “wired” means memory that the kernel keeps physically mapped. It is not just physically mapped currently, but the kernel will not unmap it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Thanks.  I'm not 100% certain my usage of "wired" matches standard Linux terminology either.  A quick search found a couple other SO answers, one using "wired" in the macOS sense, another using it the way I was, but 3 of the first 5 hits were my own comments and answers.  I may have misappropriated the word for this meaning after reading it somewhere long before that.  In Linux, unswappable user-space pages are "locked", like from `mlock`, and kernel memory in general can't be paged out.

Comment: @user129393192: distinction between "loaded" and "wired": a page from a file can be present in memory in the pagecache, even if the hardware page-tables don't map a user-space process's virtual addresses to those physical addresses.  OSes typically do that lazily even after an `mmap` or `execve`, even if all the file's data is hot in the pagecache.  (Because it's less work in case some of the pages are never touched, or evicted before touched.)

Comment: Linux `mmap(MAP_POPULATE)` (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) "pre-faults" all the pages, bringing them in from disk if necessary as well as making page-table entries to avoid even "soft" page-faults.  When memory is running low, the kernel may unmap (unwire in my earlier terminology) some pages without actually dropping them; if they are still needed, a page-fault will happen and it can wire it back up without needing to do any I/O, thus just a "soft" page fault.     (Or HW page tables may support an "accessed" bit that the kernel can clear, which will be set by hardware.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Re: "If you asked a different question", I'd actually asked it [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/160633/page-allocation-for-a-program/160636#160636) at the same time we were having this discussion and have not accepted an answer yet. Thanks for all the extra info. Now I've got a lot more I'm looking into ... like the page cache vs. anon. pages and how mem. is managed at the physical level. This stuff is really interesting to me.

Comment: @PeterCordes I’ve read elsewhere, but could you elaborate on the page cache? From my understanding, this is just files backed by disk. I’m not fully sure I get how this intermingles with the notion of swap space for anonymous (non-disk backed) pages, especially after a process calls `mmap` on it (I understand there may be some sort of copy-on-write with the kernel’s internal memory if it has it cached — which is why even with `MAP_PRIVATE`, your data you `mmap` can change). The management of this seems a bit complex to me, and not fully understood.

Comment: @user129393192: If you make a writeable MAP_PRIVATE mapping of a file, then writing to it triggers copy-on-write.  That virtual page is no longer backed by the file, it's effectively anonymous now, only backed by swap space if the system has any.

Comment: Got it. So swap space backs anonymous pages (or anything otherwise not backed by the filesystem) and the file system backs all else. I can see a few exceptions to this rule, considering things like page table directories and kernel memory.

Comment: @user129393192: Page-table directories are part of kernel memory, not a separate example.  Along with a kernel stack and a `task_struct` for per-task kernel bookkeeping. But you're right, they're not "anonymous" pages, they're not mapped by user-space at all.  It's up to the kernel whether it wants to demand-page any parts of kernel memory.  Linux for example doesn't, only paging out user-space pages.

Comment: That's interesting. I know Linux has the concept of "kernel threads" and I would've thought that those would also be swapped in and out of swap space, to avoid heavy load on memory. @PeterCordes

Comment: Couldn't you do `printf("%x",&_start);`? to find where it is?